# django how to render same template twice

Tags: python, ajax, django, jinja2

I am new to using django and am unfamiliar as to how my question should be worded.

I have been working on a new web app but noticed that the initial loading of the website is slow. My current view code is here.

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
from django.http import HttpResponse
from tools import fetcher
import requests
import json

def index(request):
    env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('templates'))
    template = env.get_template('index.html')
    template_values = {'popular_stocks': []}
    popular = fetcher.get_tops()

    for instrument in popular:
        r = requests.get('https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/%s/quote' % (instrument['symbol']))
        quote = json.loads(r.content.decode('utf-8'))
        template_values['popular_stocks'].append(quote)

    return HttpResponse(template.render(template_values))
```

Is there anyway to speed up the loading of my site by loading the initial index.html first WITHOUT any popularstocks and then submitting the fetcher.get_tops() to the template values?

I know of AJAX but I am unsure how to implement it or if that is even what I need.

Any step towards the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: The above ajax question works with different URL's but I don't want to change URL's. I want my current URL to be loaded in chunks

Comment: No other URLs need to be exposed to the end user (though, of course, their browser will see them). As far as your users is concerned they're loading one page.

Comment: (Opinion: Overloading a single URL to do multiple things is a Very Bad Idea™. It is confusing and will become a maintenance nightmare. If it feels like you're fighting against Python, Django, and HTTP itself that's probably a good sign that you're doing something wrong.)

Comment: I think I may need to re design my web app to better handle all the request data I am processing but your comment DID solve my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I'd definitely go with AJAX in this case.

Other strategy might be caching the stock prices somewhere (MEMCACHE, Redis?), thus just updating according to a cache expiration policy and not on every page load.